# Qt Android Directories

Tags: android, qt

I am concerned about two questions regarding how Qt works with Android directories.

1. For example, I want to download an archive via a library (QuaZip), but I need it to be downloaded along the path "/ storage / emulated / 0 / Android / data /", and then unzipped right there. But the problem is that the file is saved in the patch "/data/user/0/org.qtproject.example.NameApp". How can this be fixed? My code (it is unlikely that it works at all, but on Windows it would work for sure):

```
m_file.rename ("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cache.zip");
```

2. Can I open a file in Android via QProccess?

Comment: What kind of file you want to launch with QProccess? Is it some shell script, native ELF executable, installed package or other kind?

Comment: Updated my post and added example of bash command launch with QProcess. It worked.

Comment: It's apk package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## On your first question about `Android/data` r/w

On Android 11 `Android/data` is forbidden for app access without root, see [docs1](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-access-restrictions) and [docs2](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#operations-allowed-manage-external-storage).

For read/write to other locations:

1. The directory must exis or must be created (with [`QDir::mkpath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath) at once, or with [`QDir::mkdir()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkdir) by subdirectories sequentally, because it can't create trees of directories).
2. `QFile` must be closed before rename.
3. App must have `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.
4. At last, approve file access permissions manually in Android apps settings after app is deployed from Qt Creator. And you also may have to launch app manually, because there were [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24550778/12691808) about different app behavior when launched from IDE and and when launched manually from device.

This code worked for me (Android 11, Qt 5.15.2):

```cpp
bool result;
QDir dir("/storage/emulated/0");
qDebug() << dir;
result = dir.mkdir("cache");
qDebug() << "mkdir(\"cache\") success: " << result;
QFile m_file(dir.path() + "/cache/cache.txt");
result = m_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
qDebug() << "open() success: " << result;
m_file.close();
result = m_file.rename(dir.path() + "/cache/cache.zip");
qDebug() << "rename() success: " << result;
```

## On your second question about `QProcess`

This code worked for me:

```cpp
QProcess process;
process.start("touch", QStringList() << "/storage/emulated/0/new_text_file.txt");
result = process.waitForFinished(1000);
qDebug() << "waitForFinished() success: " << result;
qDebug() << "errorString(): " << process.errorString();
```

The file `new_text_file.txt` appeared on my device storage. If you specify the type of file you want to launch, I can answer more precise.

Comment: QProcess: Destroyed while process ("touch") is still running.